# FFmpeg : Attach metadata to the segment muxer

Tags: windows, audio, video, ffmpeg, libx264

I tried to attach metadata to the segment muxer using `bitstream filter` with no success, Please tell me how can do it?

Comment: Possibly a bug as it works with plain MXF output without segment.

Comment: Will look into it.

Comment: @Gyan, Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time yet to look into it. Soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MXF muxer relies on extracting extradata from each H.264 KF packet which looks to be missing when it is invoked via the segment user.

Add the following to your original command to attach the metadata

```
-bsf:v extract_extradata,dump_extra=k
```